# Knitr kable/pandoc/pander/geom_title/grid.table custom cell formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, gridextra, pander

I would like to add symbols and letters before and after some numbers when using `knitr`'s `kable` function, but do not know how to do this efficiently. I am however also willing to consider `pandoc`/`pander` if its is better/more efficient.

The end result should be an HTML table...or very good graphic of one....

Please see the following code as a mock reproducible example that is in a .Rmd file:

````
### Notional and Cumulative P&L

```{r echo=FALSE}
Notional <- 10000
yday_pnl <- -2942
wtd_pnl <- 2300
mtd_pnl <- -3334
ytd_pnl <- 5024

yday_rtn <- (yday_pnl/Notional)*10000
wtd_rtn <- (wtd_pnl/Notional)*10000
mtd_rtn <- (mtd_pnl/Notional)*10000
ytd_rtn <- (ytd_pnl/Notional)*10000

Value <- c(Notional,yday_pnl,wtd_pnl,mtd_pnl,ytd_pnl)
rtn <- c(NA,yday_rtn,wtd_rtn,mtd_rtn,ytd_rtn)

COB.basics <- as.data.frame(cbind(Value,rtn))
rownames(COB.basics) <- c('Notional','yday pnl','wtd_pnl','mtd_pnl','ytd_pnl')
```

```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}
kable(COB.basics,digits=2)
```
````

So similar to Excel's format type of currency or accountancy I would like the value field to have the $ sign for the `Value` column, and for the `rtn` column I would like to have the string `bps` after the numbers...also for readability purposes is it possible to have commas after three digits if it is before the decimal point? i.e. to represent thousands etc.

Also is it possible to colour the cells? and also colour the text/numbers too? i.e. red for negative values?

Answer (score 3):

Partial solution with `pander`:

1. Set "big mark" for `pander` so that it would be used for all numbers:

   ```
   panderOptions('big.mark', ',')
   ```
2. You can also set the table syntax to `rmarkdown` (optional, as now rmarkdoen v2 also uses Pandoc, where the `multiline` format has some cool features compared to what `rmarkdown` format offered before:

   ```
   panderOptions('table.style', 'rmarkdown')
   ```
3. You can highlight some cells with e.g. `which` and some custom R expression:

   ```
   emphasize.strong.cells(which(COB.basics > 0, arr.ind = TRUE))
   ```
4. Simply call `pander` on your `data.frame`:

   ```
   > library(pander)
   > emphasize.strong.cells(which(COB.basics > 0, arr.ind = TRUE))
   > panderOptions('big.mark', ',')
   > pander(COB.basics)

   -----------------------------------
       &nbsp;       Value       rtn   
   -------------- ---------- ---------
    **Notional**  **10,000**    NA    

    **yday pnl**    -2,942    -2,942  

    **wtd_pnl**   **2,300**  **2,300**

    **mtd_pnl**     -3,334    -3,334  

    **ytd_pnl**   **5,024**  **5,024**
   -----------------------------------

   > panderOptions('table.style', 'rmarkdown')
   > pander(COB.basics)
   |     &nbsp;     |  Value  |  rtn   |
   |:--------------:|:-------:|:------:|
   |  **Notional**  | 10,000  |   NA   |
   |  **yday pnl**  | -2,942  | -2,942 |
   |  **wtd_pnl**   |  2,300  | 2,300  |
   |  **mtd_pnl**   | -3,334  | -3,334 |
   |  **ytd_pnl**   |  5,024  | 5,024  |
   ```

---

To color the cells, you could add some custom HTML/CSS markup manually (or LaTeX if working with pdf in the long run), and the same stands also for adding `%` or other symbols/strings to your cells with e.g. `paste` and `apply` -- but pls feel free to submit a feature request at https://github.com/Rapporter/pander

Comment: I'm not amazingly familiar with pander...how would it be put into an R markdown file?

Comment: @h.l.m call `pander` instead of `kable` and probably also set table style to `rmarkdown` (see updated example) -- although the default `multiline` format is just fine for Pandoc.

Comment: Would it the file go through the knit2html() function?